# Map Multiple Columns between 2 tables in SQL server

Tags: sql-server-2008

i have 2 tables

1. [PaymentMethod]
2. [Vendor Tool Input]

**Table 1 -** `PaymentMethod` has below information

```
ComCd | AccountGroup | BankCountry | Currency | VARSPaymentMethod | SAPPaymentMethod
_____________________________________________________________________________________
SG00    ABC                         SGD         Check                  C
SG00    ABC                         SGD         Return Check           E
SG00    ABC                         Not SGD     Check                  D
SG00    XYZ                         SGD         Check                  C
SG00    XYZ                         SGD         Return Check           E
SG00    XYZ                         Not SGD     Check                  D
```

**Table 2 -** `[Vendor Tool Input]` has below information

```
VendorNo | AccountGroup | BankCountry  | ComCode | PaymentMethod | Payment Currency
__________________________________________________________________________________
TEST1      ABC                            SG00      Check           SGD
TEST2      ABC                            SG00      Return Check    SGD
TEST4      ABC                            SG00      Check           AHP
TEST6      XYZ                            SG00      Check           SGD
TEST7      XYZ                            SG00      Return Check    SGD
TEST9      XYZ                            SG00      Check           AHP
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT -**

```
VendorNo(from table 2)    |   sappaymentmethod(from table 1)
_______________________________________________________________
TEST1                                  C
TEST2                                  E
TEST4                                  D
TEST6                                  C
TEST7                                  E
TEST9                                  D
```

Here is the Query i have written but its not working it seems -

```
SELECT A.[SAPPaymentMethod] ,B.[VendorNo],B.[ComCode],B.PaymentMethod,A.Currency,B.[Payment Currency] FROM [master].[dbo].[PaymentMethod] A, [master].[dbo].[Vendor Tool Input] B Where  B.ComCode
=A.Comcd and B.AccountGroup=A.AccountGroup and B.BankCountry is null and B.[Payment Currency]=A.Currency and B.PaymentMethod=A.VARSPaymentMethod
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH CTE1 AS
(
   SELECT ComCd,AccountGroup ,SAPPaymentMethod,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY AccountGroup ORDER BY  SAPPaymentMethod) RNOPAY
   FROM PaymentMethod 
)
,
CTE2 AS
(
   SELECT ComCd,VendorNo , AccountGroup,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY AccountGroup ORDER BY VendorNo)   RNOVEN
   FROM VendorToolInput
)
SELECT CTE2.VendorNo,CTE1.SAPPaymentMethod 
FROM CTE1 
JOIN CTE2 ON CTE1.AccountGroup=CTE2.AccountGroup AND CTE1.RNOPAY=CTE2.RNOVEN
AND CTE1.ComCd=CTE2.ComCd
```

- **[Click here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2fb09/1) to view Result**

Comment: Hi Sarath, You have not considered Currency Field and Bank Country for Mapping. There also need to be considered.

Comment: If you take **CurrencyField** in join, then you will get only **TEST1,TEST2,TEST6,TEST7**. For the third entry in **ABC** in **PaymentMethod** table, the value of **CurrencyField** is **Not SGD** and the the third entry in **ABC** in **VendorToolInput** table, the value of **CurrencyField** is **AHP**. How can we combine that! @baimzz

Comment: thats the challenge Sarath, IF Currency is other than SGD, that means it can be AHP,INR,USD etc, we have to get TEST4 and TEST9 as well where Currency is not matching.

Comment: Give **AND (CTE1.Currency = CTE2.[Payment Currency] OR CTE1.Currency <> CTE2.[Payment Currency])** in **WHERE** clause. @baimzz